# Split data from database column & view as string using Laravel

Tags: laravel-5.7

[image] I have inserted multiple string in a column as an array in my database. They are separated by coma(,).

[image] In the view page for route no 1 there are 3 stoppage points. Now I want to show them separately into different input fields. But they are shown into same filed as an array. So what should I do...?

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
   <div class="group">
      <label>Stoppage Point</label>
      <input type="text" value="{{ $allroute->stoppagePoint }}" name="stoppagePoint" class="input1 removeDis {{ $errors->has('stoppagePoint') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" disabled required>
      @if ($errors->has('stoppagePoint'))
      <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
      <strong>{{ $errors->first('totalStoppage') }}</strong>
      </span>
      @endif
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to execute it inside the blade template or do the logic in the controller

But i think the best way is to use the controller

You can use `explode` php function

```
$stoppages = explode(',',$points->stoppagePoints);
```

then this creates an array then you can append it to the view

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach (explode(',', $allroute->stoppagePoint) as $stoppagePoint)
    <input type="text" value="{{ trim($stoppagePoint) }}" ...
@endforeach
```